# IE 6-8 float:left does not seem to work

Tags: css, css-float, html

My [site](http://www.dijkmeijer.com/ellen) (in dutch) displays correctly on firefox and safari (mac + pc), chrome (mac, pc not tested) but not on IE 6-8 (unavaible for mac). I think I there is something wrong with my div's or css layout but I can't get my finger behind it, And I'm not really an html / css expert. I do not have IE currently to test with.
IE somehow ignores the float:left and moves the second and third column completely to the bottom of the screen, only the upper border is visible. What is wrong?

Cheers,
Jeroen.

Comment: http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.dijkmeijer.com%2Fellen%2F&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have to specify a "doctype" for internet explorer to "behave" normally :
Something like that should do the trick :

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
```

Also you might want to consider using a css reset (so that css behave coherently across all browsers ..). I'm using [the one from meyerweb](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/) but they are many others.

Also it seems your using a combination of tables AND floating divs. I'm not sure if you really need a float for your design anyway .. you could consider absolute positioning as your layout seems fixed ..